# WPF and routed event

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I have a WPF window, which has a button that is inside a stackPanel, which is inside another stackPanel

I wrote an event handler for the button for the MouseDown event.
I want to execute this eventHandler three times for the button and the parent (stack panel) and the parent's parent

How can I achieve that with the routed event, by writing only one event handler?
I don't want to repeat the event handler code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a method to be called from the event handlers of the Button and StackPanel's.
2. Sets the Handled property of the args to false.
3. Or you can have a Boolean parameter in your GenericHandler method so that you can decide whether it should let the event bubble.

   ```
   void GenericHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   ```

   {
       // Check for the type of the args here and do your work.

   ```
   args.Handled = false; // this lets the event bubbled up.
   ...
   ```

   }